# "p4 interchanges" lists a changelist that has already been integrated

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

I'm running `p4 interchanges -b my_branch`, and I get a ton of results, the first one being a changelist that we integrated a long time ago.

So I try to integrate again, but `p4 integrate -b my_branch //...@changelist,@changelist` just returns "All revision(s) already integrated".

The only way to unblock this is to do a forced integration (`-f` in the integrate command) and then simply accept target (`-at` when resolving), and that works - `p4 interchanges` then no longer lists this changelist.

But how can Perforce get into this state to begin with? This happened after we've done a bunch of integrating across multiple branches, but I nothing that I'd think would cause a changelist to become "unintegrated" somehow.

This is on a 2014.1 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for specifying your server version.

The 'p4 interchanges' command can give the "All revision(s) already integrated" message with misleading results when cherry-picking is involved.

There is a command line example here:

```
http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Cherry-Picking-Integrations
```

You could also be affected by a bug that was patched in 2014.1 listed here in the server release notes:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/relnotes.txt

Bugs fixed in 2014.1 PATCH5

```
#880506 (Bug #71725) **
    The istat.mimic.ichanges configurable controls the reporting
    of revisions between stream and parent.  If set, istat will
    not report cherry-picked revisions already present in the target.
    The default behavior will report any changes not credited, even 
    when the content may already be in the target.
```

If you would like, you can pull the most recent build of the server P4D for your OS from our ftp site: http://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r14.1/

REFERENCE

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Integration-Changes-Reporting

Comment: Thanks! To clarify, we're on 2014.1/907894. It could be cherry-picking, but the problem is that "interchanges" pointed the CL out previously, we integrated it, and "interchanges" struck it off the list. And now, months later and several random integrations later, it came back out of nowhere.

Comment: That's a pretty complex scenario. I'd suggest talking directly with Perforce Technical Support.

Comment: It seems that "integrate -f" and a resolve caused that, and continues to cause it sometimes. We received a pretty detailed investigation of what's going on, but this answer is good enough.